# Can I typecast a field for retrieval only in Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, api, eloquent, laravel-8

Can I typecast a field on the fly in Laravel? I really don't want to store the data in the database with all the backslashes. If I don't have the `protected $casts` in the `ReportData` model, it will store it as I want, but then I have to in my javascript later use `JSON.Parse(report.data)`, usually multiple times in multiple places. So when I added the `protected $casts` I no longer had to do that, but now it stores it with escaped data.

So can I store it without using the `protected $casts`, but then transform it / mutate it, cast it, but just that one `data` column of the `reports_data` table?

Report Model

```
class Report extends Model {
    public function data()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ReportData',"report_id","id");
    }
}
```

ReportData Model:

```
class ReportData extends Model {
    protected $casts = [
        'data' => 'json',
    ];
    public function report()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Report',"id","report_id");
    }
}
```

API to retrieve:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $reports = Report::where('id', $request->id);
        if($request->with_data) {
            $reports = $reports->with('data');
        }

        return $this->response->collection($reports, new ReportTransformer);
    }
```

API that stores:

```
private function query_data(Request $request, $query_id) {
    $record = new ReportData;
    $record->title = $request->name;
    $record->report_id = $request->id;
    $record->data = json_decode($request->input('data'), true);
    $existing_record->save();
}
```